# How to test values in second table with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm currently trying to get the length of the second table of my web page.

I have the impression that you can't do two "get" in the same line (as you can see below).

```
cy.get('table').eq(1).get('tbody>tr').its('length').should('be.gt', 1)
```

So my approach is to access the second table from where the".eq(1)", and to do a get from behind to get my lines back.

[image]

This is what the page looks like, and the highlighted line is the table I want to test.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`within`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Syntax):

> Scopes all subsequent `cy` commands to within this element.

For example:

```
cy.get('table').eq(1).within(() => {
  cy.get('tbody>tr').its('length').should('be.gt', 1)
})
```